# Formik catch-22

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm new to React and I've run into a catch 22 situation when using Formik that I seem to have a mental block with.  If I use withFormik() then my component can't use hooks in its submit handler.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Form, Field, withFormik } from "formik";
import { useDatabase, useAlerts } from "./Hooks";

const MyForm = props => {
  const { resetForm, dirty, isSubmitting, setSubmitting } = props;
  const { loadData, saveData } = useDatabase();
  const { success } = useAlerts();
  const reset = data => resetForm({ values: data });

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData().then(data => reset(data));
  }, []);

  // Problem: How can I execute this on submit?
  const handleSubmit = async values => {
    await saveData(values);
    reset(values);
    success("Values saved");
    setSubmitting(false);
  };

  return (
    <Form>
      <h1>Catch 22</h1>
      <Field
        name="firstName"
        placeholder="First name"
        readOnly={isSubmitting}
      />
      <Field name="lastName" placeholder="Last name" readOnly={isSubmitting} />
      <input disabled={!dirty} type="submit" />
      <input type="reset" />
    </Form>
  );
};

export default withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: () => ({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: ""
  }),
  enableReinitialize: true,
  handleSubmit: () => {
    // Has no access to saveData() and success() hook methods
  }
})(MyForm);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-blackburn-q1mt4?file=/src/MyForm.js

Alternatively if I don't use withFormik then I can't reset the form when my data has loaded because I don't have a reference to resetForm.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Form, Field, Formik } from "formik";
import { useDatabase, useAlerts } from "./Hooks";

const MyForm = props => {
  const { loadData, saveData } = useDatabase();
  const { success } = useAlerts();

  // Problem: how can I reset the form on data load?
  useEffect(() => {
    loadData().then(data => resetForm({ values: data }));
  }, []);

  const initialValues = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: ""
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
    await saveData(values);
    resetForm({ values });
    success("Values saved");
    setSubmitting(false);
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      enableReinitialize={true}
    >
      {({ isSubmitting, dirty }) => (
        <Form>
          <h1>Catch 22</h1>
          <Field
            name="firstName"
            placeholder="First name"
            readOnly={isSubmitting}
          />
          <Field
            name="lastName"
            placeholder="Last name"
            readOnly={isSubmitting}
          />
          <input disabled={!dirty} type="submit" />
          <input type="reset" />
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default MyForm;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-sound-048wf?file=/src/MyForm.js

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that writing out the problem triggered some mind-cogs to start turning and I came up with a possible solution.

I introduced a context like this...

```js
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { useDatabase } from "./Hooks";

export const DataContext = React.createContext(null);
export const DataContextConsumer = DataContext.Consumer;
export const useDataContext = () => useContext(DataContext);

export const DataContextProvider = props => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: ""
  });
  const { loadData, saveData } = useDatabase();
  const load = async () => setData(await loadData());
  const save = async newData => await saveData(newData);
  const contextValues = { load, save, data };
  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={contextValues}>
      {props.children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const withDataContext = () => WrappedComponent => props => (
  <DataContextProvider>
    <WrappedComponent {...props} />
  </DataContextProvider>
);

export default {
  DataContext,
  DataContextConsumer,
  DataContextProvider,
  useDataContext,
  withDataContext
};
```

And then passed its data to Formik's initialValues.  Now Formik gets the new values on load and I can call the save hooks in the submit hander.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Form, Field, Formik } from "formik";
import { withDataContext, useDataContext } from "./DataContext";
import { useAlerts } from "./Hooks";

const MyForm = () => {
  const { load, save, data } = useDataContext();
  const { success } = useAlerts();

  useEffect(() => {
    load();
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = async (values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
    await save(values);
    resetForm({ values });
    success("Values saved " + JSON.stringify(values));
    setSubmitting(false);
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={data}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      enableReinitialize={true}
    >
      {({ isSubmitting, dirty }) => (
        <Form>
          <h1>Catch 22</h1>
          <Field
            name="firstName"
            placeholder="First name"
            readOnly={isSubmitting}
          />
          <Field
            name="lastName"
            placeholder="Last name"
            readOnly={isSubmitting}
          />
          <input disabled={!dirty} type="submit" />
          <input type="reset" />
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default withDataContext()(MyForm);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-cache-txnit?file=/src/MyForm.js

Perhaps this is a classic case of solving a React problem by [lifting state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: Is your primary concern to have the initial form values populated from loadData?

Answer (score 0):

You can lift the form inside the render prop for `formik` up into a new component allowing you to use hooks inside it. Now you can move the `loadData` effect into the lifted form and know that you are now defining the effect inside of both scopes where you can get access to `resetForm` via the render props and `loadData` via the `useDatabase` hook.

```
const LiftedForm = ({ isSubmitting, dirty, resetForm }) => {
  const { loadData } = useDatabase();

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData().then((data) => resetForm({ values: data }));
  }, [loadData, resetForm]);

  return (
    <Form>
      <h1>Catch 22</h1>
      <Field
        name="firstName"
        placeholder="First name"
        readOnly={isSubmitting}
      />
      <Field name="lastName" placeholder="Last name" readOnly={isSubmitting} />
      <input disabled={!dirty} type="submit" />
      <input type="reset" />
    </Form>
  );
};
```

and passing the formik bag via the render props right to the new lifted form component.

```
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      enableReinitialize={true}
    >
      {(props) => <LiftedForm {...props} />}
    </Formik>
```

The `handleSubmit` needs no changing because it already receives everything it needs in the callback and has access to `saveData` and `success` via hooks.

```
  const { saveData } = useDatabase();
  const { success } = useAlerts();

  const handleSubmit = async (values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
    await saveData(values);
    resetForm({ values });
    success("Values saved");
    setSubmitting(false);
  };
```

the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-forest-ts80s?file=/src/MyForm.js) for that